# Build Nested structure using BeamSQL

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, beam-sql

In BigQuery we have "ARRAY_AGG" function which helps to convert the normal collection to Nested collection. Is there a similar way to build same kind of nested structure collection using BeamSQL?. Something like below query in BeamSQL,

> "Select column1, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(column2, column3)) from PCOLLECTION Group by Column1"

Comment: Google Cloud Dataflow actually has a SQL product in alpha now. Dataflow Cloud SQL is trying to match BigQuery SQL's functionality. Right now ARRAY_AGG in BQ is not supported by Cloud Dataflow SQL though (what is supported is is in https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/sql/).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you should be able to use `ARRAY` constructor like `"SELECT ARRAY[1, 2, 3] f_arr"`, [this passes](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/8727):

```java
  @Test
  public void testArrayConstructor() {
    BeamSqlEnv sqlEnv = BeamSqlEnv.inMemory(readOnlyTableProvider);
    PCollection<Row> stream =
        BeamSqlRelUtils.toPCollection(pipeline, sqlEnv.parseQuery("SELECT ARRAY[1, 2, 3] f_arr"));
    PAssert.that(stream)
        .containsInAnyOrder(
            Row.withSchema(Schema.builder().addArrayField("f_arr", FieldType.INT32).build())
                .addValue(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
                .build());
    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish(Duration.standardMinutes(2));
  }
```

See also:

- [Calcite SQL reference guide](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html) (it is the parser used by Beam SQL);
- [Beam complex types test](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/BeamComplexTypeTest.java);
- [Beam nested rows test](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/BeamSqlDslNestedRowsTest.java)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess your sample code and reference will support with Nested row in BigQuery, but not with 'Nested row with repeated'. Anyway let me explore it with these example/reference and let you know my feedback. I am looking for Nested Row with Repeated.